# Rubber Ducky with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash-scripting

So, i'm trying to run a file from the Ducky on WIndows 10, when I get to the part of:

```
STRING for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %A in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart ^| findstr "DUCKY"') do (set DUCKYdrive=%A:)
```

It opens the cmd prompt, as it is supposed to, it inputs the string, opens another cmd prompt with DISKPART, but that's all. It just hangs there. When I close the DISKPART cmd, it goes to the other cmd and says it can't find the file/file location. This does work with no issues on Windows 7, so Im thinking WIndows 10 just takes a different command that I am unaware of.

Comment: What do you mean by "***Ducky on Windows 10***"

Comment: Rubber Ducky - But that doesn't really have to do with it completely. The command shown, if I run in command prompt, it does nothing.